# ATK4 and file upload

Tags: atk4, php

I am using  `controller_filestore` and it gives error Method `addCondition` is not defined neither in `controller_filestore`, nor in its Model. If I use controller_filestore_image, it doesn’t find the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Model_Filestore_File or Controller_Filestore_File for conditioning.

Example is here:
http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/filestore